# Static UITableView on iPhone 5

Tags: uitableview, height, iphone-5, autolayout

The main screen of my app is a static table view with some options. With the new iPhone 5 I have to deal with an extra space on the bottom of the screen: I would like to increase the height of the cells accordingly to the screen dimension and to scale, consequently, the labels font size inside it. Is there any way to do it using only using autolayout? If not which is the best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's good practice to stretch a table view's cells for the iPhone 5 resolution. The reason they gave you more pixels is so users could see more of the screen.

If you insist on doing this, you can set the row height in your table view delegate method, checking the screen height to see if it 568 points (the iPhone 5 height) using `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height`:

```
// sets the height for a row based on indexPath
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // check if the iPhone 5 is used by using the screen height
    BOOL isIPhone5Used = ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568.0f);

    // set the height to a larger number for iPhone 5 rows
    return (isIPhone5Used ? 50.0f : 44.0f); // this sets a height of 50 for iPhone 5 rows, and 44 for all other iPhones

}
```

You should customize it depending on the `indexPath`, if you use different heights for various rows. Or, return one value if all rows are the same height.

Comment: I agree with you but unfortunately the screen use a static table for displaying a dashboard and in 4'' mode it shows a really annoying empty space because I don't have more element to show.

Comment: Do you think I can use Auto-Layout for the label font size inside the cell or shall I write some for it?

Comment: I think you'll have cleaner and more manageable code by converting the static table view into a dynamic one and then using `tableView: heightForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: Are you sure you need to display everything with a UITableView? If you're trying to fill the screen exactly, adding some UIView subclasses with the objects you need might work better. And they can be set to AutoSize for any phone resolution.

Comment: I know,but it's a porting and we have already a lot of code in place. Next app I will definitely use subviews to layout my static screen. Do you know if AutoLayout constraint can resize a UILabel according to vertical constraints?

Comment: It should be doable, but I'm not sure about exact implementation. I've been avoiding AutoLayout since it's not supported before iOS 6.